# slicing periodically for a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array `a = np.arange(100)` including 100 numbers.
I wondered to know is there a way to slice it periodically rather than using the conditional statements.

for example, if I want to slice the 1st four numbers + 5th four numbers + 9th four numbers and so on and finally have all these in one array.

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: have a look at advanced indexing, that may help

Comment: actually, it's not clear what you're asking for.  We can surely help if you provide an example of expected output

Comment: sure, let say I have an array [1 2 3 ... 99 100]
and I want to take out these numbers which occur periodically (1 2 3 4 17 18 19 20 33 34 35 36 ...). the numbers are following a pattern which is 1st four-numbers + 5th four-numbers + 9th four-numbers and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.resize` to transform the array into two dimensions, then slice the rows as required. Just be wary that there is an edge case if `a` is not an exact multiple of 4.

```
import numpy as np

wt = 4
a = np.arange(100)
ht = int(a.size/wt)
a.resize(ht, wt)
n = a[0::4,].flatten()
print(n)
```

Output:

```
[ 0  1  2  3 16 17 18 19 32 33 34 35 48 49 50 51 64 65 66 67 80 81 82 83
 96 97 98 99]
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, I think that is the best way to do that as I couldn't find any other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(100)
grp = 4
grp_no = [1,5,9]
lst = np.array([a[range(n*grp-4, n*grp)] for n in grp_no])
print(lst)
print(lst.flatten()) #if required
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [16 17 18 19]
 [32 33 34 35]]
[ 0  1  2  3 16 17 18 19 32 33 34 35]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am looking for a more comprehensive method. My real dataset is very big and I want to continue slicing to the last numbers in my array.

Comment: One liner and truly pythonic solution. Can you please detail what do you mean by comprehensive ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want a strided index - I don't know of numpy tooling that does that completely vectorized, but it probably exists.

This solution selects indices idx_arr from `a`.  The only un-vectorized (slow) component is the loop over stride groups; everything else should be fast.  Notice in particular pre-populating :

```
nmax = 10000
m = 4
a = np.random.rand(nmax)
_sub_arr = np.arange(m)
idx_arr = np.concatenate([_sub_arr + 4*m for m in range(0, int(nmax/m), 4)])
sol = a[idx_arr]
print(sol)
```